# Interpreting Root Mean square Error (RMSE )when dependent variable is log transformed

Tags: regression, data-visualization, python, interpretation, intuition

So I have developed a model to predict the house prices in a county.I log transformed the target variable (home price).I split the data into training and testing sets.I trained the model on the training set and tested it on the testing set.

[image: Here is the regression plot of Actual Y values vs predicted y values]

The R2 for this model is 0.665 and the RMSE is 0.201.How do I interpret the RMSE?How do I explain it in layman's terms?
I know that its the measure of how far the predicted values are from the actual values, but as the target variable is log transformed, how can I convert the RMSE in USD form? Ideally, I would like to report that the difference between the actual home prices and the predicted home prices is xUSD.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314490/regression-rmse-when-dependent-variable-is-log-transformed

Comment: If the ultimate goal is to model house prices, the model does not do that until the model predictions are "de-transformed". Only then can you find the predicted price, rather than the log of the predicted price. After the de-transform you would need to recalculate R2 and RMSE on the original house prices in dollars with model predictions in dollars. Consider the regression as a part of your modeling, rather than the entirety of the modeling.

Comment: So I fit the model on log transformed data, and test it on detransformed data?

Comment: If the purpose of taking the log was to allow linear regression to be used rather than non-linear regression, then the log is an artifact of the modeling process. In such cases, the process is: 1) take logs 2) fit linearly 3) take anti-logs. If non-linear fitting is used, this presents a different set of problems, but interpreting the fit statistics without data transformations (and de-transformations) is straightforward. Without the de-transform you have not done step 3, but rather stopped at step 2, and have a modeling process that gives the log of house price.

Comment: A better, more modern alternativ could be to use a glm (generalized linear model) with log link function. That should give better predictions.